# How to copy a sheet to an other workbook

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I am trying to copy the active sheet to an other workbook, but for some reasons that I do not know I am not succeeding (even after looking for other posts with solutions that seemed to work). How can I accomplish this?

Here is my code:

```
If CheckBox2 = True Then
    direccionar = Application.GetOpenFilename(, , "Select database")
    Set sourcewz = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=direccionar)
    l = sourcewz.Worksheets.Count
    namico = HojaActiva.Name
    namico.Select
    Sheets(namico).Copy after:=Workbooks("Base de pedidos YA procesados.xlsm").Sheets(Sheets.Count)
End If
```

I am getting this error:

> error 9 subindex out of interval

Comment: What happens if `direccionar` is not an excel file?

Comment: `direccionar` wouldn't be an Excel file. The `GetOpenFilename` returns a `Variant`. If the user pressed Cancel it is a boolean value `false`, otherwise it is a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens because Excel cannot find your workbook `"Base de pedidos YA procesados.xlsm"`.
Do you want to copy a Worksheet named `HojaActiva` to the Workbook you are trying to open?

In that case use this code:

```
Dim direccionar as Variant
direccionar = Application.GetOpenFilename(, , "Select database")
If direccionar = False Then    'Check if the user pressed Cancel'
    Exit Sub
End If
Set sourcewz = Application.Workbooks.Open(Filename:=direccionar)
HojaActiva.Copy After:=sourcewz.Sheets(sourcewz.Sheets.Count)
```

Comment: Firts thank you for your help. In second place, now it does a copy but not of the sheet needed which is named in the code as hojaactiva, I've tryed this modification but still doesnt work... direccionar = Application.GetOpenFilename(, , "select database")
    Set sourcewz = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=direccionar)
    whisky = HojaActiva.Name
    Application.Sheets(whisky).Copy After:=sourcewz.Sheets(sourcewz.Sheets.Count)

Comment: Check the edit I made. I thought you were trying to copy the `ActiveSheet`. I know HojaActiva means ActiveSheet in Spanish, the name is misleading :) Now it should work.

Comment: Thanks man!! it works!! it does mean that but Vba takes it as a simple variable as VB editor is just like "britishh" jajaja